# padding-top issues in div

Tags: css, html

I have a div and for some reason there are regular scrollbars on the page even though there is nothing in the div. The div is set to 100% height and overflow:auto but the scrollbars still appear even when there is no content.

To test something, I put the following in the div style:

```
padding-top:500px
```

What it did was leave that 500px space from top and then display the text I had but after that the same amount of space was there too.

So it was something like this:

```
|       |
| 500px |
|       |
| xxx   |
|       |
|       | -> See that extra space after the content?
|_______|
```

Please help

---

**HERE IS SAMPLE CODE:**
http://jsfiddle.net/Saq4T/

Comment: Would you mind posting your div sample? It could be something small, but it helps to have the whole picture in HTML / CSS.

Comment: Please mark previous questions as answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Padding` is added on to the overall height, not included in it. Read about the [box model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html).

Therefore, a div with 100% height and 500px padding really 100% + 500px tall.

Add `margin-bottom:-500px;` if you still want padding but don't want the scrollbar.